# Парсер после авторизации

Tags: curl, php, парсер

Здравствуйте.

Вот я написал код авторизации, как после этого парсить? Забыл уточнить, на языке программирования PHP, методом cURL.

Comment: @romaaa32, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: парсить что? куда? зачем? :<